# I'm trying to print QTableWidget as pdf in PyQt5, but i'm getting this glitch

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtextdocument

While trying to print QTableWidget I'm getting this glitch where last row is inserted into last column of the 2nd last row, I don't know why is this happening.

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked.

Here is the code:

```
    document = QTextDocument()
    cursor = QTextCursor(document)
    table = cursor.insertTable(
        self.students_reports_table.rowCount(), self.students_reports_table.columnCount())
    for col in range(table.columns()):
        cursor.insertText(self.students_reports_table.horizontalHeaderItem(col).text())
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)


    for row in range(table.rows()):
        for col in range(table.columns()):
            cursor.insertText(self.students_reports_table.item(row, col).text())
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)
    document.print_(printer)
```

And here is the output. As you can see clearly in this image last row is in last column of 2nd row:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code you create the table with a same amount of rows that in your table widget. Then you immediately fill one of those rows with the header labels.  So when you go to fill in the table with data from the widget, there is one less row than needed to fit all the data.

Try setting up the table with `students_reports_table.rowCount() + 1`.

```
table = cursor.insertTable(
    self.students_reports_table.rowCount() + 1,  # use rowCount + 1
    self.students_reports_table.columnCount()
)
```

Comment: Now it gives this error ```    self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())
  File "C:/Users/Ahmad/PycharmProjects/ProjectWatchdog/Admin_Panel2.py", line 1241, in handlePaintRequest
    cursor.insertText(self.students_reports_table.item(row, col).text())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'```

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad  That line has nothing to do with this portion of your code... read the error message, it is talking about handling paint requests.  So it is unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Alexander the OP is probably trying to access an *empty* item or using the wrong row count.